# Apache camel netty delimiter

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, jms, netty

I want to use a different delimiter *(asterik) for tcp data received from gps device. By default it is newLine character.

```
 from("netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:5557?textline=true&sync=false&tcpNoDelay=true").bean(DataReceiverService.class,"decisionMaker")
```

I read the netty documentation it says that it only accepts "LINE" and "NULL" as value and LINE is the default.

TCP data format is:

```
$ 96,.,.,.,.,,.,5,.,.,. * (Starting with dollar and ending with an asterik).
```

Comment: You need to use a custom codec in netty with the asterik as end chrachters. You may be able to configure nettys text codec to use asterik instead of new line. And then configure Camel netty endpoint to use your codec

Comment: Thanks. Is there any example of it ? I am using the configuration as given above.

Comment: There is an example here that uses a custom codec: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-netty-custom-correlation - the stuff about custom correlation is not needed in your case, so you can omit that.